# Conformal flatness FLRW

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, conformal-field-theory

1. The FLRW metric is known to be conformally flat, i.e., it is conformally related to the Minkowski metric. How I read this, is that it makes the FLRW metric expressible in static form. Is this correct?
2. According to Florides [1], the only FLRW spacetimes that are expressible in static form are the 6 FLRW spacetimes of constant curvature, that is, Minkowski, Milne, deSitter (flat, open, closed) and Anti-deSitter.

The first and second statement combined suggest the FLRW spacetime can only be of one of these 6 forms. Is this correct?

The evolving concordance model is not among them. So what to make of this?

[1] Florides, P.S. The Robertson-Walker metrics expressible in static form. Gen Relat Gravit 12, 563–574 (1980).

Comment: If $H$ is independend of $t$ like it is in the metrics you mentioned above you can use static coordinates, but if it is time dependend you can't

Comment: You don't need staticity for conformal flatness

Comment: @Yukterez, of course, but the statement of Florides is about the opposite: if expressible in static coordinates (the FLRW metric is conformal to Minkowski) then the FLRW metric can only be one of these 6.

Comment: @Eletie: indeed. Florides shows that, given Minkowski (or any other static representation of FLRW), the solution set of expanding FLRW spacetimes is restricted to Milne and (A)dS. The implicit statement seems the FLRW metric is a (energy) conservation equation, therefore, restricts what you can put into the stress energy tensor if space expands.

Comment: 1. Whether an FLRW metric is static or not depends on the solution to Einstein equations. For example for inflation, the scale factor is time dependent

Comment: The scale factor $\rm a$ can be time dependend in a static metric, but $\rm \dot{a}/a=H$ can not

Comment: @Yukterez good point. I guess I was thinking about Minkowski form specifically.

Comment: @Octaff I'm not sure where you're getting that FLRW needs to be static for conformal flatness? That isn't what Florides is claiming. E.g. the FLRW metric with constant spatial curvature in conformal coordinates has a timelike conformal killing vector, but not a normal timeline one.

Comment: @Eletie I’m sorry, that’s not what the question says.

Comment: Statement 2) above in the exact words of Florides: “It is shown that there are six, and only six, Robertson-Walker metrics which can be expressed in static form. They are precisely those Robertson-Walker metrics whose spacetime curvature is constant.” And these include, e.g., the expanding dS spacetime

Comment: Yes, that's fine. In point 1 when you say 'How I read this, is that it makes the FLRW metric expressible in static form' is the incorrect part. There's no link between conformal flatness and the staticity requirements in your item 2.

Comment: Expressible in static form is not the same as being static

Comment: There still seems to be some confusion here: there is no need for the FLRW metric to be expressed in static form for conformal flatness, because of the conformal factor. The Weyl tensor vanishes for *all* FLRW metrics, for arbitrary $a(t)$. Florides is looking at constant *spacetime* curvature solutions - there's no connection here.

Comment: @Eletie, true, all are conformally flat. But due to Florides, the actual solution set is limited to those 6 of constant curvature. All Florides uses is the FLRW metric. Hence there must be an implicit constraint in the FLRW metric (I would say conservation of energy) from which Florides arives at these 6. All others fail to satisfy this undefined implicit property, therefore cannot exist as FLRW solution, if Florides is correct.

Comment: This is somewhat speculative on my part, but seems the only possible conclusion if both statements are correct.

Comment: I disagree, constant curvature solutions are not the only physically allowed FLRW solutions. They just happen to have constant curvature. In the Florides paper he's studying them just for mathematics sake. The conservation constraint (continuity equation) is automatically satisfied for any FLRW solution, not just these constant curvature ones.

Comment: Well, there is no time translation symmetry in expanding FLRW space in general. And the continuity equation does not prevent photons from being redshifted. But the point of my question is mathematical in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

The flat FLRW metric in static spherical [Schwarzschild/Droste-style](http://notizblock.yukterez.net/viewtopic.php?p=1053#p1053) coordinates is

$$g_{\mu \nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \rm c^2-H^2 r^2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{\rm H^2 r^2/c^2-1} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \rm -r^2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \rm -r^2 \sin ^2 \theta \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

or in [Gullstrand/Painlevé-style](http://f.yukterez.net/einstein.equations/files/23.html) proper distance raindrop coordinates

$$g_{\mu \nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \rm c^2-H^2 r^2 & \rm H \ r & 0 & 0 \\
 \rm H \ r & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \rm -r^2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \rm -r^2 \sin ^2 \theta \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

or the [cartesian form](http://f.yukterez.net/einstein.equations/files/35.html) with $\rm \{ t,x,y,z\}$ instead of $\rm \{ t, r, \theta, \phi \}$

$$g_{\mu \nu}=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \rm c^2-H^2 (x^2+y^2+z^2) & \rm H \ x & \rm H \ y & \rm H \ z \\
 \rm H \ x & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 \rm H \ y & 0 & \rm -1 & 0 \\
 \rm H \ z & 0 & 0 & \rm -1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

but if $\rm H$ is not constant and you have a time dependend Hubbleparameter the whole metric becomes time dependend, so that is only static when the other densities are neglible compared to the dark energy density. Then we have basically [De Sitter](http://f.yukterez.net/einstein.equations/files/28.html) space where $\rm H=c \sqrt{\Lambda/3}$ is constant, or Minkowski if you also set $\Lambda=0$.

In our universe this will be the case in a few billion years when the Hubble radius becomes asymptotically constant, see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Yl6Seq17LY) at around $\rm  t > 35 \ Gyr$ where $\rm H$ doesn't really change anymore. During [inflation](https://org.yukterez.net/inflation.png) the Hubbleradius $\rm c/H$ is also expected to be constant, so that era can also be described in static coordinates.

For $\rm H$ to change you need $\rho$ to change, and then your [curvature](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kretschmann-Skalar)

$$ \rm K=12 (2 H^4+2 H^2 \dot{H}+\dot{H}^2)/c^4$$

is no longer constant (since the $\rm \dot{H}=dH/dt\neq 0$) and the metric is no longer static, but rather $\rm t$-dependend. With $\rm \dot{H}=0$ the curvature invariant reduces to $\rm K=24H^4/c^4$ and the requirement of constant curvature that your reference presumes for static coordinates is fulfilled. I haven't read it though, but since you quoted it yourself:

> Octaaf quoted Florides: *"the only FLRW spacetimes that are expressible in static form are the 6 FLRW spacetimes of constant curvature"*

I don't expect it to be different there.

Comment: That still leaves the question: all FLRW spacetimes satisfy the FLRW metric, so can be conformally represented by static Minkowski. But then,  according to Florides, can only be of constant curvature. Hence the question.

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric#Hyperspherical_coordinates. This article makes clear that the FLRW spacetimes satisfying the FLRW metric can include alternative geometries in addition to having flatness or constant curvature.

Comment: Yes, but any FLRW geometry is still conformally flat, so that does not change the question, which by Florides’ result suggests that only those of constant curvature are admissible.